# How to display four sides scrollbars on JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I have JScrollPane that contains a panel like  `JScrollPane scrollWindow = new JScrollPane(window);` I overrided `getPreferredSize()` to display the scrollBars on the right and the bottom when I drag a shape outside the screen, that's worked fine
The problem is when I drag to the left or the top, no scrollbars shows.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: An SSCCE would be very helpful to solve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A JScrollPane doesn't have the concept of displaying scrollbars for negative values. All Swing components start at (0, 0) and increase in width and height.

If you want to drag components to a negative position then you will to recalculate the position of all components to be translated by the negative value of the dragged component.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that the ui only defines 2 scollbars: right and bottom. You might be able to add 2 additional scrollbars using the `setColumnHeaderView` and `setRowHeaderView` methods and synchronize them somehow (using a listener etc.).